# Use Ubuntu laptop as second monitor

Tags: 16.04, graphics, windows, display

So I have an Windows 10 computer, a VGA/HDMI cable, and an Ubuntu 16.04 HP Laptop. Is there any way to use my laptop as a second screen to my Windows computer, but still see Ubuntu UI and all that? Like to have a window opened on Ubuntu seeing my Windows computer.

I don't want any remote software like TeamViewer.

Comment: Short answer: No, it can't be done.

Answer (score -1):

You will most likely need software to accomplish this. Synergy will allow you to share the mouse and keyboard, which would make it feel somewhat like the same machine.

http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: True, but that wasn't the question. was it?

Comment: Noooo, I want to use my laptop as a second screen, but still see Ububtu's UI beacuse I gotta  know the battery